# Tracing an algorithm

Tags: loops, trace

Describe the sequence of operations when calling getSpend with “P3” as the
parameter. What will the returned value be?

CODE:

```
public class Spends {

  private String[] d = {"P1", "10", "15", "P2", "12",
  "23", "38", "P3", "3", "P4"};

  public int getSpend(String id) {

  int spend = 0;

  boolean done = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < d.length && !done; i++) {
      if (d[i].equals(id)) {
        for (int j = i-1; j >= 0 && isAmount(d[j]); j--) {
          spend += Integer.parseInt(d[j]);
        }
        done = true;
      }
   }
   return spend;
}
```

public boolean isAmount(String s) {

return s.charAt(0) != 'P';

}

Answer (score 1):

I'm making an assumption about the routine `isAmount()` since it's not specified what language this is, so I don't know if it's a builtin, or provided elsewhere, e.g. as a member function of class Spends.

Whatever the case, I'm going to assume that it returns `true` if it's parameter is a pure integer encoded as a string, i.e. `"10"`, and it returns `false` if there's a non-numeric in the string, e.g. `"P1"`

Now, let's look at the outer loop: that'll step up the `d` array till it finds `"P3"`.  That'll make `i` equal to 7.

What does the second loop do?  Think about how it initializes its control variable `j`.  What member of the `d` array will it be indexing for its first iteration?

Will that member pass the `isAmount()` test?  If so, what happens, in particular how is `spend` modified?

On to the next iteration. Where is `j` indexing in the `d` array now?  Will it pass the test, and if so what happens to `spend`?

Do you now see the pattern of what it's doing?  How far will `j` go before it exits the loop?  What members of the `d` array will it have iterated over, and how will it have modified `spend` with those values?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the function "isAmount()" . i have added it now. the language is java